# Disable force-close when batch file being called has an error

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

If the title seems vague, What I mean is that if you call a batch file through `cmd` or another batch file, how do you make it that the batch file being called, when it has an error, does not force-close the batch file that is calling it? My purpose is that if the batch file being called has an error, I won't redirect `stderr` to null, I'll just show it, and i'll make the launcher automatically (user choice) run debug mode or what most people call `@echo on` lol, and make the user reproduce the error.
[HERE](http://pastebin.com/UXPiM8mW) is the batch file (Launcher) that calls the program.
[HERE](http://pastebin.com/ZrCQ7NCL) is the program that is being called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`call` will run the program in the current shell process. `cmd /c` (or perhaps `%COMSPEC% /c`) will run it in *another* process, thus allowing you to catch errors.

So, the calling batch file might be changed from

```
call easycommandline.bat
```

to

```
cmd /c easycommandline.bat
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
    REM Do stuff when the script returns an error.
)
```